# flask route how to process data after redirect

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I got this problem:
How to set process data in FLASK after redirecting?

```
@main.route('/sendfile',methods=['POST'])
def process_file():
    file=request.files['file']
    filename=secure_filename(file.filename)
    file.save('/save/'+ str(filename))
    file_for_process='/save/'+ str(filename)
    process_file_fuction(file_for_process,pathtosave)<<<<HERE IS
    return redirect(url.for('main.processed')
```

So my processing function is too long, what should i do to redirect and after process file? May be it is better to add another view?
thanks!
Its would be great if you send me some code example on github or good tutorial, because i cannot find where file is sending, redirecting to page with 'YOUR FILE IS STILL PROCESSING' and once its gone show result. All tutorial are just about sending file, but not processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the user to the `main.processed` page and then process the file. To send the file and its contents over you can pass in the data as arguments as such: `redirect(url.for('main.processed', data=data, more_data=data)`. To access them you can use `request.get('data')`. I hope this helped!